# How to set Overlap Anchor on Spinner Programmatically, in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I need to be able to toggle the Overlap Anchor property of Spinner programmatically. But I cannot find the method relating to this

I tried using `'setDropDownVerticalOffset(int pixel).'` But it is not what I need. The positioning of the dropdown here changes when the view is at different positions on the screen or when the size of the list is different.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any publicly available method to do that. The `overlapAnchor` attribute is actually applied to an internal `PopupWindow`, and that only happens during construction. There's also no public method to access that `PopupWindow`, AFAICT. Apart from modifying the `Spinner` class yourself, the simplest thing to do might be to programmatically swap out the `Spinner` as needed with one that's inflated with that attribute set appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM.
I think, I will follow your advice and use an already inflated Spinner. I was also thinking of just including an xml file which I can inflate here.